# Succes ajax no está respondiendo, no devuelve los mensajes

Tags: javascript, ajax

Dispongo del siguiente código en el que la llamada a php (envía mail y guarda los mensajes de confirmación) sí funciona pero ajax no devuelve los mensajes de confirmación. ¿Podrían ayudarme?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#subscribe').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var postdata = $('#subscribe').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/assets/subscribe_process.php',
            data: postdata,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                if(json.valid == 0) {
                    $('.success-message').hide();
                    $('.error-message').hide();
                    $('.error-message').html(json.message);
                    $('.error-message').fadeIn();
                }
                else {
                    $('.error-message').hide();
                    $('.success-message').hide();
                    $('#subscribe').hide();
                    $('.success-message').html(json.message);
                    $('.success-message').fadeIn();
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group">
  <form id="subscribe" class="input-group" role="form" action="/assets/subscribe_process.php" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" aria-label="E-mail">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary submit_btn" type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </span>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="success-message"></div>
<div class="error-message"></div>
```

Código php.

```html
<?php

// Email address verification

function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i", $email));
}

if($_POST) {

    // Enter the email where you want to receive the notification when someone subscribes
    $emailTo = 'correo@hotmail.com';

    $subscriber_email = addslashes(trim($_POST['email']));

    if(!isEmail($subscriber_email)) {
        $array = array();
        $array['valid'] = 0;
        $array['message'] = 'Introduzca una dirección email válida.';
        echo json_encode($array);
    }
    else {
        $array = array();
        $array['valid'] = 1;
        $array['message'] = '¡Me pondré en contacto con usted!';
        echo json_encode($array);

        // Send email
     $subject = 'Nuevo contacto';
     $body = "Un usuario ha enviado su email\n\nEmail: " . $subscriber_email;
        // uncomment this to set the From and Reply-To emails, then pass the $headers variable to the "mail" function below
     $headers = "From: ".$subscriber_email." <" . $subscriber_email . ">" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $subscriber_email;
     mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Dentro de la función del success pon console.log(json) para ver que trae y recorrerlo adecuadamente. Es probable que no salga bien por el parseado datos datos en origen.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, efectivamente, el json no estaba bien formado. Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Nada, ya lo tienes o necesitas ayuda con el formato del json en origen?

Comment: No, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.