# Succes ajax no está respondiendo

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy adaptando un template html para mi sitio. Tengo un problema con el formulario de contacto. Javascript no está respondiendo y no muestra los mensajes de confirmación y/o error. El código que me proporciona la plantilla es el siguiente (he probado una solución alternativa con el script de esta otra prengunta: [Succes ajax no está respondiendo, no devuelve los mensajes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/175403/succes-ajax-no-est%c3%a1-respondiendo-no-devuelve-los-mensajes) , pero tampoco consigo que muestre los mensajes. Un script php sencillamente envía un mensaje, que sí lo hace, está fallando es el código javascript.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    (function($) {
        "use strict";


    jQuery.validator.addMethod('answercheck', function (value, element) {
        return this.optional(element) || /^\bcat\b$/.test(value)
    }, "type the correct answer -_-");

    // validate contactForm form
    $(function() {
        $('#contactForm').validate({
            rules: {
                name: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                subject: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 4
                },
                number: {
                    required: false,
                    minlength: 5
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                message: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 20
                }
            },
            messages: {
                name: {
                    required: "come on, you have a name, don't you?",
                    minlength: "your name must consist of at least 2 characters"
                },
                subject: {
                    required: "come on, you have a subject, don't you?",
                    minlength: "your subject must consist of at least 4 characters"
                },
                number: {
                    required: "come on, you have a number, don't you?",
                    minlength: "your Number must consist of at least 5 characters"
                },
                email: {
                    required: "no email, no message"
                },
                message: {
                    required: "um...yea, you have to write something to send this form.",
                    minlength: "thats all? really?"
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                    type:"POST",
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    url:"/assets/contact_process.php",
                    success: function() {
                        $('#contactForm :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        $('#contactForm').fadeTo( "slow", 1, function() {
                            $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                            $(this).find('label').css('cursor','default');
                            $('#success').fadeIn();
                            //$('#success').fadeIn()
                            $('.modal').modal('hide');
                   $('#success').modal('show');
                        })
                    },
                    error: function() {
                            $('#contactForm').fadeTo( "slow", 1, function() {
                            $('#error').fadeIn();
                            //$('#error').fadeIn()
                            $('.modal').modal('hide');
                   $('#error').modal('show');
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
 })(jQuery)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact_form">
  <div class="main_title">
    <h2>Puede contactar conmigo:</h2>
    <p style="text-align:justify">Con el siguiente formulario recibirá una respuesta gratuita y confidencial.</p>
  </div>
  <form class="contact_us_form row" action="/assets/contact_process.php" method="post" id="contactForm" novalidate="novalidate">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nombre">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="number" name="number" placeholder="Teléfono">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Asunto">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
      <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="1" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn submit_btn2 form-control">Enviar mensaje</button>                                         </form>
</div>

<div id="success" class="modal modal-message fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                        </button>
                        <h2>Gracias</h2>
                        <p>Su mensaje ha sido enviado...</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Modals error -->

<div id="error" class="modal modal-message fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                        </button>
                        <h2>Lo sentimos</h2>
                        <p>Algo salió mal</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: En lugar de `.ajaxSubmit({` intenta `.ajax({`

Comment: Pero... ¿qué tendría que ocurrir en el `success`? por ejemplo, no veo que recibas ningún tipo de respuesta dentro del método. ¿Verificaste que no hay errores en `contact_process.php`?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta alanfcm, no ha sido la solución. contact_process.php no tiene errores, hace su función, sólo envía un mail y este sí que se envía, pero al realizar el submit queda en vacío en la ejecución de contact_process y no muestra los div que el sucess debería mostrar.